# log off/restart to apply changes

Tags: windows-7, remote

I get a message that  I have to log off in order to apply some changes I did at Windows 7 (to which I am remotely connected), can I restart it instead? because I put automatic login at startup therefore it will automatically login after restart but not sure if it will act in the same way if I log off

Answer (score 2):

Yes, restarting is a valid alternative to logging off to apply changes to in-use files, whatever they may be.

Comment: it is possible that you will be "blind" to the update part post logoff/reboot till you can get a working powershell/gui